# Unable to install .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I want to test my app in release mode so I changed the schemes and then tried to run it on my device when it said `"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"`

Then I archived the file, code signed it and then exported an `.ipa` file, for `Enterprise and Ad-Hoc testing`, to run on my device. I tried to install this with the `iPhone Configuration Utility` and even then it gave me the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check code-signing under Build settings, for AdHoc or release is it pointing to right Certificate i.e., Ad-Hoc Cert and Provisioning profile ?

Comment: Oh. I just checked. It is pointing towards a iOS distribution certificate. I wanted to test it in release mode to check if my push notifications and the corresponding APNS settings were working properly. So this means that I have to create a new ad-hoc provisioning profile?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, is it to see why IPA wouldn't install on the particular device ?

Comment: I am trying to check if the push notifications are working with the distribution certificates.

Comment: Are you on an Enterprise account or standard/company account?

Comment: I'm on a standard account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the bundle ID. When you create Distribution certificate with the bundle ID which was used for testing purpose , then it will be blocked for Distribution and release purpose. So even if you re-create Ad-HOC certificate with the same bundle ID(Which was used for Distribution cerfiticate) it does not work.

Try adding a new bundle ID and create new certificate with the new ID. It WORKS....

Thanks
Jithen